# Como executar um comando VBA numa folha com nome especifico?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Tenho um documento de Excel com várias folhas. Nesse documento preciso executar um comando numa folha especifica, ou seja pelo nome da folha. Mas se essa folha não existir executar outro comando numa outra folha com nome especifico até acabar as folhas.

Exemplo:

```
Sub adicionar_categorias()

folhas = Array ("FOLHA 1", "FOLHA 2", "FOLHA 3")

For i = LBound(folhas) To UBound(folhas)
Worksheets(folhas(i)).Activate

Range("X2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Computadores>Portáteis"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("X2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("X2:X" & Lastrow)

Next i
End Sub
```

Se a folha não estiver no livro vai dar erro **Worksheets(folhas(i)).Activate**! Como resolver o erro?

RESOLVIDO: **On Error Resume Next**

```
Sub adicionar_categorias()

folhas = Array ("FOLHA 1", "FOLHA 2", "FOLHA 3")
On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(folhas) To UBound(folhas)
Worksheets(folhas(i)).Activate

Range("X2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Computadores>Portáteis"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("X2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("X2:X" & Lastrow)

Next i
End Sub
```

Obrigado "dot.Py!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff838003.aspx), pode chamar o método `.Activate`, que é equivalente a clicar na guia da planilha nomeada como `"Plan1"` na sua pasta de trabalho.

```
Worksheets("Plan1").Activate
```

---

Ao invés de referenciar pelo nome, pode referenciar pela posição da aba na sua pasta de trabalho, como por exemplo:

```
Worksheets(0).Activate
Worksheets(1).Activate
Worksheets(2).Activate
```

Onde numa pasta de trabalho recém-criada, a `Worksheets(0)` equivale à `Plan1`, a `Worksheets(1)` à `Plan2` e a `Worksheets(2)` à `Plan3`.

Lembrando que se alterar a ordem das abas manualmente, apesar de o nome não mudar, a posição mudará...

---

Pode também criar uma `array` com os nomes das planilhas que deseja ativar, e rodar um for para cada item dentro desse array.

```
planilhas = ("plan1", "plan2", "plan3", "plan4")

For i = 1 to UBound(planilhas)
    Worksheets(planilhas(i)).Activate
Next i
```

Para melhorar esse código, você pode acoplar um `try/catch/finally` ou um [`On Error Resume Next`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement) p/ que o programa saiba o que fazer quando a aba existe, e o que fazer quando não.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário dot.Py!

Comment: Sim, mas e se a folha não existir. Como é que resolvo o erro e continuo o loop?